# How to fetch only specific columns of a table in django?

Tags: python, django

I have seen that queries like :

```
user = User.objects.all() or User.objects.filter(username = username)
```

will fetch all the columns of the table even if we do not need all the columns. Do we have a better way of writing a database query? and if yes why do we not see that code most often?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

[`QuerySet.only()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.only) and [`QuerySet.defer()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.defer) can be used to refine which fields the ORM will pull, deferring the others until the appropriate attributes on the models are accessed.

Answer (score 43):

With django 1.8:
use the values_list

```
Entry.objects.values_list('id', 'headline')
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/

Comment: I found this to be the most appropriate answer.

Answer (score 6):

if you need just the values as a dictionary use objects.values(''). Its also faster.

see docs: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-fields